# How do I create a condition based on published test results within a TFS 2012 build template?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'd like to make use of the "Team Foundation Server Build Extensions Power Tool" to import JUnit test results into TFS within a custom build template designed to run Maven build through TFS.

The importing part works fine, but the overall build status is not set correctly: If any tests fail, it ends in "Succeeded" and not in "Partially succeeded". This seems to be a shortcoming of the Power Tools.

A possible workaround would be to set the build status (the TestStatus in particular) in an explicit activity. I'd like to do that based on a condition activity that checks if any of the imported tests have failed.

However, this seems not to be easy to do, and I'd like to avoid creating a custom activity for this purpose.

Can you give me some hints on how to formulate a condition in a TFS 2012 build template that checks if any of the then already imported tests have failed?

Answer (score 0):

The condition expression I was looking for is:

```
BuildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.GetService(Of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementService).GetTeamProject(BuildDetail.TeamProject).TestRuns.ByBuild(BuildDetail.Uri).SelectMany(Function(tr) tr.QueryResults()).Where(Function(tcr) tcr.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Failed).Any()
```